# Binary numbers in Java Least Significant

Tags: java, binary

Im trying to write a method that returns me the least 2 significant binary numbers of any number from 0 to 255 both inclusive, which returns it in decimal, apparently I could use mod operator % but I dont know what to do because with this method it doesnt return me the correct 2 least sig. For 19, it should return 3 since the last 2 significant (11) are equal to 3 in decimal

```
public static int getLeastSignificant2( int num )

{

    int first = num<<6

    int finalD = first>>>6;

    return finalD; 
}
```

Comment: The question, and the code doesn't make sense in it's current form, I suggest you rewrite it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be able to bitwise and the number by 3 (11 in binary). This would zero out all the other bits except the 2 least significant bits.

```
public static int getLeastSignificant2(int num) {
    // return num & 3; // if you don't want to use a binary literal
    return num & 0b11;
}
```

with this I get `System.out.println(getLeastSignificant2(19)); //=> 3`

if you wanted to use the mod operator could do this. I think the compiler ends up converting this to use a bitwise and under the hood.

```
public static int getLeastSignificant2(int num) {
    int modResult = num % 4;
    return modResult < 0 ? modResult + 4 : modResult;
}
```

Edit: Modified to handle negative numbers as noted by @dave_thompson_085

Comment: Is there another way to do that without binary literals? Like I wonder how to do it with mod operator % because they told me to use it as a hint.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Note `n % powerof2` is not the low bits for **negative values** (at least for two's-complement representation as Java requires); that is not a problem for this Q (limited to 0:255) but can be in other cases.